# Sharing subtrees in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a database table that stores a tree of data for users. A user can share arbitrary subtrees of this data with other users, and any changes made to the original subtree should be seen by anyone who has access to the shared subtree.

Here is an example:

```
Library
- Divider A (Shared with user Y)
  - Divider B (Shared with user Z)
     - Divider C
       - Subject D
```

I would like to use the ltree extension for this, but it seems like the shared subtrees don't work well with the path data that I would need to store with the individual nodes. If the path for a node is different for different users, I would need to copy the nodes and add them with different paths, and whenever the shared tree changed, I would need to find all the copies and update them too. For example, the path for users X and Y from the top to the bottom of the tree would be A.B.C.D, but it would be B.C.D for user Z, who should not be aware that node A even exists.

Is there an alternative way that I could store tree data to avoid this problem? What is the best way to handle shared subtree data like this in Postgres?

Comment: What kind of changes do you make to the tree and how?

Comment: Just subtract a prefix from the paths if a user can only see a part of the tree. The prefix identifies which subtree the user can see.

Comment: The tree can have new nodes added or deleted, or can have nodes rearranged (in the example above, C and D could swap places).

Comment: Subtracting the prefix could work. I think I'd need to track the roots of the subtrees that were being shared with individual users to know what to subtract.

Comment: You'll are already tracking the subtree (by its root) anyway for the sharing in the first place, unless you put a separate surrogate key on them you'd just identify them by the "prefix" path anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I had the totally same problem in my current project using `ltree`. I solved it by implementation of access control list, using a second table.

So in your case you can insert into the `rights` table, something like this:

```
INSERT INTO rights (user_id, path) values ('Y', 'A');
INSERT INTO rights (user_id, path) values ('Z', 'A.B');
```

Request for all library data, shared for user `Z`, will look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM library 
WHERE path <@ ARRAY(select path from rights where user_id = 'Z')
```

Maybe one day I will get rid of the subquery, but so far this solution works well.

---

My table structure for reference:

[image]